# Why use a signed int for a counter?

Tags: database, types, youtube, int

In [this article](https://plus.google.com/+youtube/posts/BUXfdWqu86Q), youtube talks about changing from 32 bit ints to 64 bit ints to count views. However, the math implies they are using a signed int. If I understand this correctly, why use a signed int for a counter, there doesn't seem to be any obvious need to store negative values?

Comment: Are they using Java, where you have no choice but to waste half the range for every variable you'd ordinarily - in a language which offers you the choice such as C++ - use an unsigned version of the type?

Comment: It could be the back-end database.  For instance sql server doesn't support native unsigned types.